# how to call a html file from a controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I know how data can be passed between a controller and view and vice-versa.

In node.js, we can render html files with the data using express.js.

Is it possible to do the same with angularjs?

For example:

```
$scope.edit = function(id) {
    EmployeeService.editEmployee(id).then(function (response) {
        if(!response) {
            console.log("no response");
        } else {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

In the above logic, I need to render "**edit.html**" file with the **response.data**.

Comment: Do you want to render `edit.html` in a modal or in the same window?

Comment: same window where i am showing all employees.

Comment: So you will replace all employees `<div>` or `<table>` with the `edit.html`?

Comment: no i have a form in edit.html file. i just want to fill it with the response data.

Comment: Yes, but is the `edit.html` file loaded in your html via a `<script>` tag or have you put it in the `$templateCache`?

Comment: edit.html file is kept under views folder. from the controller file, i need to call that html file with the response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `ng-include` directive to achieve this:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div id="all-employees" ng-show="!selectedEmployee">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>Options</td>
            <tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
              <td>{{ $index }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.age }}</td>
              <td><button ng-click="edit($index)">Edit</button></td>
            <tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id="selected-employee" ng-hide="!selectedEmployee">
        <div ng-include="'views/edit.html'"></div>
        <button ng-click="selectedEmployee = undefined">Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**lib/script.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, EmployeeService) {

  $scope.employees = [
    {name: 'test', age: 24},
    {name: 'guest', age: 29},
    {name: 'fest', age: 39}
  ];

  $scope.edit = function(index) {
    EmployeeService.editEmployee(id).then(function (response) {
        if(!response) {
          console.log("no response");
        } else {
          $scope.selectedEmployee = response.data;
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
  };

  $scope.unsetSelection = function() {
    $scope.selectedEmployee = undefined;
  };
});
```

**views/edit.html**

```
<div>
  <h3>Employee Detail</h3>
  <div>{{ selectedEmployee.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ selectedEmployee.age }}</div>
</div>
```